# android studio won't start anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I lost my mind with this problem! My android studio has suddenly stop working without any reason! The log I receive is this:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
... 1 more
```

But I don't know which port is used.
Hope someone can help me to figure out a solution to this problem!
OS: Windows 10 Release (build 19043.985)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006880600-IDEA-Start-Failed-Address-already-in-use

Command used:

```
netsh winsock reset
```